# How do i pass the last else in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying make a if, elif list comprehension line... found this code in other question:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> ['yes' if v == 1 else 'no' if v == 2 else 'idle' for v in l]
['yes', 'no', 'idle', 'idle', 'idle']
```

My question is: Can I pass the last 'else' as a third action?
I've tried use pass but got a syntax error.

I have this:

```
# list = [(code, qty),(code, qty)]
>>>storehouse = [('BSA2199',2000),('PPF5239',251),('BSA1212',989)]
>>>buyList = [(cod, 1000) if qty < 200 else (cod, 500) for cod, qty 
in storehouse]
```

I want to ignore the items that are > 1000.

Thanks, hope I had made my self clear(first question in here).

Comment: So your expected output is `['yes', 'no']`?

Comment: `['yes' if v == 1 else 'no' for v in l if v in {1, 2}]`?

Comment: Actually you can remove items using the `if` clause: `[x+1 for x in range(10) if x % 2]`

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra list comprehension express mapping/filtering operations `[<some expression> for x in iterable if <some predicate expression>]`

Comment: My bad. And I actually used it for filtering.

Comment: @It_is_Chris actually,  i'm working with "<" and ">" Like if x < 200, do it, if x < 1000 do that, and i can't find a way that says: if x > 1000 do nothing.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: @AdaoBMF You've already been shown how to do it. It's simply: `buyList = [(cod, 1000) if qty < 200 else (cod, 500) for cod, qty in storehouse] if qty <= 1000`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Wasn't realized yet, the if after the for, does the work. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *first* filter for the desired values, at the outer `for` expression.
Within that, you choose your yes/no response:

```
['yes' if v == 1 else 'no' 
       for v in l    if v in [1, 2]]
```

Output:

```
['yes', 'no']
```

Answer (score 1):

I might encode this relationship in a dictionary so you can use it for both the filtering and the mapping:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> d = {1: 'yes', 2: 'no'}
>>> [d[v] for v in l if v in d]
['yes', 'no']
```